# Diffing Two Arrays in RxJs

Tags: javascript, arrays, rxjs

You've seen this question before, but I want to understand the flow of this question in RxJs.

```
array1 = ["cat", "dog", "taco"]
array2 = ["cat", "dog", "fish"]
```

Filter *array2* to only show items not in *array1*. Expected result:

```
result = ["fish"]
```

**What Works:** `array1.map(value1 => array2 = array2.filter(value2 => value1 !== value2));`

Maybe there is a better way?

Comment: Are you talking about arrays or rxjs? In Rxjs the concept of filtering a stream based on another stream sounds terrible. If they are just arrays, I'd do `array2.filter(value2 => !array1.includes(value2))`

Comment: `includes()` is awesome, but our projects have to use IE 9 and 10. Of course, there is [this big, ugly polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#Polyfill) available. I'm dealing with Observables, not arrays, but I wanted to find a relationship since RxJs gives us some of the same (and a lot more) functionality. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: else you have the hack `array1.indexOf(value2) >= 0`, but this doesn't work in some edge cases like dealing with objects I think

Answer (score 1):

You don't need rxjs to do the diffing. You can use any library which provides the diffing function. For instance, if you use `ramda`, the `difference` operator does just this. Cf. http://ramdajs.com/docs/#difference.

I believe the same method exists also with `underscore`.

If you would do this with Rxjs, you cannot escape a O(nm) algorithm. You might be more lucky with a specific algorithm for a given library (say if you have big arrays to diff).

Comment: "but I want to understand the flow of this question in RxJs."

Comment: right, but `the flow of this question in Rxjs` makes no sense. You don't diff arrays in rxjs, you diff arrays. In rxjs, you process streams. So if you turn your question into a question on streams, you will get more chance to get an answer you can use.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to diff two observables?
Here is my solution:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.3.0/Rx.js"></script>
    <script>

    const observable_a =  Rx.Observable.interval(2000).take(10);//0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
    const observable_b = Rx.Observable.interval(1000).map(x=>x+3).take(5);//3,4,5,6,7

    
    function observableDiff(a,b,filter) {
        if(!filter) {
            filter = (value_to_check,blacklist_array)=>{
                return blacklist_array.indexOf(value_to_check)===-1;
            };
        }
        return Rx.Observable.create(observer=>{
            let a_values = [];
            let b_values = [];
            let a_completed = false;
            let b_completed = false;
            
            a.forEach(a_value=>{
                if(b_completed) {
                    if(filter(a_value,b_values)) {
                        observer.next(a_value);
                    }
                } else {
                    a_values.push(a_value);
                }
            }).then(()=>{
                a_completed = true;
                if(b_completed) {
                    observer.complete();
                }
            });
            
            b.forEach(b_value=>{
                b_values.push(b_value);
            }).then(()=>{
                b_completed = true;
                a_values.forEach(a_value=>{
                    if(filter(a_value,b_values)) {
                        observer.next(a_value);
                    }
                });
                a_values = [];
                if(a_completed) {
                    observer.complete();
                }
            });
        });
    }
    
    observableDiff(observable_a,observable_b).subscribe(console.log);//0,1,2,8,9
    
    </script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

You can also go here for other solutions:
[Diffing two Observables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46975216/diffing-two-observables)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Hi, I'd like to point out for future readers, that while this algorithm works fine to find which elements in A do not exist in B (as required in the original post), it's not a full diff since the opposite is not true. If you swap observable_a and observable_b, as the [3, 7] elements range is included in the [0, 9] range, nothing will be emitted at all. A real diff would either require two different outputs or an object with distinct properties to identify what exists in each that doesn't in the other (what was added or removed, in the common diff sense).

Comment: @Stéphane Seyvoz real diff that matches your definition would need to wait for both observables to complete. That would defeat purpose of using observables instead of arrays