# Diffing two Observables

Tags: arrays, rxjs, diff, observable, array-difference

I'm looking for a best way to Diff two Observables.
Filtered values from ObservableA should be emited as soon as ObservableB completes without waiting for ObservableA to complete.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.3.0/Rx.js"></script>
    <script>

    const observable_a =  Rx.Observable.interval(2000).take(10);//0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
    const observable_b = Rx.Observable.interval(1000).map(x=>x+3).take(5);//3,4,5,6,7

someDiffObservable(observable_a,observable_b).subscribe(console.log);//should output 0,1,2,8,9
    
    </script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
const a$ = Rx.Observable.interval(2000).take(10).share();
const b$ = Rx.Observable.interval(1000).map(x=>x+3).take(5);

Rx.Observable.combineLatest(
    a$.buffer(
      b$.startWith(null).last().concat(a$)
    ), 
    b$.toArray(),  
    (aItems, bItems) => aItems.filter(a => !bItems.includes(a))
  )
  .concatMap(filteredItems => Rx.Observable.from(filteredItems))
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.2/Rx.js"></script>
```

Comment: This solution does not work correctly when observable B is empty completed stream.

Comment: Nice catch. It was because of the last() operator, which expect at least one value. I fixed it by adding a dummy value using the 'startWith' operator

Answer (score 0):

Currently i've came up with following function to diff two observables.

Is there a simpler/faster/better way to achieve this?

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.3.0/Rx.js"></script>
    <script>

    const observable_a =  Rx.Observable.interval(2000).take(10);//0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
    const observable_b = Rx.Observable.interval(1000).map(x=>x+3).take(5);//3,4,5,6,7

    
    function observableDiff(a,b,filter) {
        if(!filter) {
            filter = (value_to_check,blacklist_array)=>{
                return blacklist_array.indexOf(value_to_check)===-1;
            };
        }
        return Rx.Observable.create(observer=>{
            let a_values = [];
            let b_values = [];
            let a_completed = false;
            let b_completed = false;
            
            a.forEach(a_value=>{
                if(b_completed) {
                    if(filter(a_value,b_values)) {
                        observer.next(a_value);
                    }
                } else {
                    a_values.push(a_value);
                }
            }).then(()=>{
                a_completed = true;
                if(b_completed) {
                    observer.complete();
                }
            });
            
            b.forEach(b_value=>{
                b_values.push(b_value);
            }).then(()=>{
                b_completed = true;
                a_values.forEach(a_value=>{
                    if(filter(a_value,b_values)) {
                        observer.next(a_value);
                    }
                });
                a_values = [];
                if(a_completed) {
                    observer.complete();
                }
            });
        });
    }
    
    observableDiff(observable_a,observable_b).subscribe(console.log);//0,1,2,8,9
    
    </script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, I'd like to point out for future readers, that while this algorithm works fine to find which elements in A do not exist in B (as required in the original post), it's not a full diff since the opposite is not true. If you swap observable_a and observable_b, as the [3, 7] elements range is included in the [0, 9] range, nothing will be emitted at all.
A real diff would either require two different outputs or an object with distinct properties to identify what exists in each that doesn't in the other (what was added or removed, in the common diff sense).

Comment: @Stéphane Seyvoz real diff that matches your definition would need to wait for both observables to complete. That would defeat purpose of using observables instead of arrays.